# Python "REPLACE" command in a SQL query(Error message)

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, replace

I am new in python and I need this query to check my database if it is working. There are lots of queries but it is only one of them.

```
import pyodbc
db_file = 'C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\bbbb.mdb' #define the location of your Access file
odbc_conn_str = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s' %(db_file) # define the odbc connection parameter
conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor() # create a cursor
sql_update_statement = "UPDATE NUMARATAJ SET KAPINUMERIK = IIf (ISNUMERIC (LEFT (REPLACE(KAPINO,'-','/'),4)=-1),LEFT(KAPINO,4))" # edit the SQL statement that you want to execute
cursor.execute(sql_update_statement) # execute the SQL statement
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

---

When I try to run this code it says;

```
  File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\aa2a.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_update_statement) # execute the SQL statement
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Sürücüsü] Undefined 'REPLACE' function in the expression. (-3102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

How can I fix it, or get it work, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
sql_update_statement = "UPDATE NUMARATAJ SET KAPINUMERIK = LEFT(KAPINO,4) WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT(REPLACE(KAPINO,'-','/'),4)"
```

However, *Replace* is a VBA function, not Access SQL, so that is probably why you receive the error.

Try simply:

```
sql_update_statement = "UPDATE NUMARATAJ SET KAPINUMERIK = LEFT(KAPINO,4) WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT(KAPINO),4)"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several "VBA functions" that were not directly supported by the older "Jet" ODBC driver (`Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)`) but *are* directly supported by the newer "ACE" ODBC driver (`Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)`). `Replace` is one of those functions.

So if you really need to use the `Replace` function you can download and install the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine Redistributable and use the newer ODBC driver.